# Basic Sproutcore: class method, class variables help

Tags: sproutcore

This is how i am defining a simple class with instance variables and instance methods.

```
ExampleClass = SC.Object.extend({
    foo:undefined,
    bar: function() {
        this.foo = "Hello world";
        console.log( this.foo );
    }
}

// test
var testInstance = ExampleClass.create();
testInstance.bar();    // outputs 'Hello world'
```

Could anyone help me out with a similar example of class variable (or similar behavoir), and class method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class Method/Property would be done like:

```
ExampleClass = SC.Object.extend({
  foo:undefined,
  bar: function() {
    this.foo = "Hello world";
    console.log( this.foo );
  }
}

ExampleClass.mixin({
  classFoo: "foo",
  classBar: function() {
    return "Bar";
  }
})
```

Then you can access it like:

```
ExampleClass.classFoo
```

But don't forget that when accessing a property (or computed property) on an instance, that you need to use `.get()` like:

```
var example = ExampleClass.create();
// Good
example.get('foo');
example.set('foo', 'baz');

// BAD!! Don't do this, or Bindings/ Observes won't work.
example.foo; 
example.foo = 'baz';
```

Comment: Thanks, just what i was looking for. Cheeky question:- do you know if it is possible to have a custom getter or setter given that one accessor (get() or set()) is used for all properties?

Comment: Yes, this is another major reason we have get/set. Have a look here: http://guides.sproutcore.com/core_concepts.html#computed-properties

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that this would work - i think having one accessor function that acts as both getter and setter depending on calling context threw me, but it does work great. Thanks for your help.