# Sproutcore 2 - Class methods and variables

Tags: sproutcore

I have been implementing class methods as shown in this answer

[Basic Sproutcore: class method, class variables help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103577/basic-sproutcore-class-method-class-variables-help)

but it no longer works in Sproutcore 2:-

```
MyFooClass.mixin({
    barClassMethod: function() {
        /* ... */
    }
})
```

gives error

> MyFooClass.mixin [undefined] is not a
>   function

I have tried reading through the Sproutcore source and couldn't really identify any Class methods or variables, which quite surprised me.

Maybe i'm just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you should keep in mind when extending a sproutcore class.

First you have to define your class before you can mix something into it. So start by creating your class/object either with

```
MyFooClass = SC.Object.extend({ ... });
```

or

```
MyFooClass = SC.Object.create({ ... });
```

whereas the first statement would create a class and the second statement a concrete implementation of a class (to speak in object-oriented terminology a object). Normally, if you are using SC.Object.create() the goal is to create a singleton-object otherwise define your class with SC.Object.extend() and use the defined class to create objects of your defined class with

```
myFooObject = MyFooClass.create();
```

So make sure your class or object you want to mix in methods is defined first and is already in scope when you want to use it.

Second, if you want to mixin additional methods or properties into an pre-existing class or object use SC.mixin as follows

```
SC.mixin(MyFooClass, {
    yourMixedInMethod: function() {
        console.log('mixed in method called');
    }
});
```

you can do this with objects as well but be aware that only the given object gets the mixed in method and not all instances of the class. If you want all instances to get the additional functionality you have to mix into the class definition.

Comment: Thanks. I had the class already defined. For some reason MyFooClass.mixin(MyClassMethods) used to work fine. Changing it to SC.mixin(MyFooClass,MyClassMethods) got it working again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
MyFooClass.reopenClass
```